# How to add typescript and reactjs in symfony?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, symfony

I'm trying to find on how to add reactjs and typescript in symfony but I found nothing. I'm trying here if there is someone who can help me on how to do it. I try this `https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html`

I'm confuse if this will work properly because it generates folders.
I use this CDN for react.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

It works fine if I use react.js but no typescript added. I used PHPStorm for this.